# PHP sorting associative array according to price

Tags: php

I want to sort a php associative array according to price in case of `token` and yearly price in case of `subscription` plan

Here is the exmaple:

```
    $packs = [
        [
            'name' => 'starter',
            'type' => 'token',
            'price' => 199
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'business',
            'type' => 'subscription',
            'price' => [
                'monthly' => 19,
                'yearly' => 219,
            ]
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'professional',
            'type' => 'subscription',
            'price' => [
                'monthly' => 9,
                'yearly' => 119,
            ]
        ],
    ]
```

I want to get a result like this

```
    [
        [
            'name' => 'professional',
            'type' => 'subscription',
            'price' => [
                'monthly' => 9,
                'yearly' => 119,
            ]
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'starter',
            'type' => 'token',
            'price' => 199
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'business',
            'type' => 'subscription',
            'price' => [
                'monthly' => 19,
                'yearly' => 219,
            ]
        ],
    ]
```

I tried this kind of solution but it returned an array with price in the key, but don't need price as key

```
    $price = [];

    foreach( $packs as $key => $value ){
        if( $value['type'] == 'token' ){
            $price[intval($value['price'])] = $value;
        }
        if( $value['type'] == 'subscription' ){
            $price[intval($value['price']['yearly'])] = $value;
        }
    }
    krsort( $price );

    $new_packs = [];
    foreach($price as $k => $value){
        $new_packs[] = $k;
    }

    //print_r($new_packs) // it returned same as the given array
```

Answer (score 2):

*but it returned an array with price in the key, but don't need price as key* Ok, but you are literally doing it in `$price[intval($value['price'])] =`  and likewise.

Don't use `krsort`. Use `ksort` (Since you want the ordering in ascending order)

Also, you just have to use `$value` instead of `$k` to take only the array values like below, because `key => value` is the syntax for foreach and here `$k` is your key and `$value` is your value.

```
<?php

$new_packs = [];
foreach($price as $k => $value){
    $new_packs[] = $value;
}
```

OR

A better alternative is to simply use [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) like below:

```
$new_packs = array_values($price);
```

Comment: tried this but not working.

Comment: @TickTwitch You used `krsort` instead of `ksort`. Works fine for me. See https://3v4l.org/sSe8I. The `array_values` version works too https://3v4l.org/3eBlj

Comment: @TickTwitch Did you try the above comment? Any update?

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($packs, function ($a, $b) { 
    return $a['price']['yearly'] ?? $a['price'] <=> $b['price']['yearly'] ?? $b['price']; 
});
```

Comment: Please do not add code only as answer. Describe what the code do

Comment: ...see also [answer]. An explanation is at least as valuable as the code itself